# 제 번역을 확인해 주시길 바랍니다~

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

### 한국인 분들~ 다음 내용의 문법, 어휘 이용, 조사 등을 확인해 주시길 바랍니다!!!~ 감사합니다~

베트남-한국: 25년간의 성공적인 협력

1992년 12월 22일에 베트남과 한국은 공식적으로 외교관계를 수립했습니다. 이는 양국 관계의 기반을 다지는 중요한 계기입니다. 지난 25년간 베트남과 한국은 강력한 발전을 달성했으며 모든 분야에서 큰 성과를 거두었습니다.

지난 25년간에, 베트남과 한국의(양국의) 관계는 정치, 경제, 협력 개발, 문화, 국민 교류 등 모든 분야에서 빠르고 견고하고 전면적으로 발전해 나가고 있습니다. 양국 관계의 발전 과정에 중요한 계기는 2001년 “전면적인 협력관계” 로, 2009년 “전략적 협력동반자 관계”로 격상하는 것입니다. 양국 고위지도자간의 방문과 접촉 또 각급 간의 교류가 빈번히 이루어져 왔으며 많은 양방협력체제가 수립되었습니다.

정치적 관계와 함께 양국간의 경제 협력관계는 특히 무역, 투자, 원조사업, 관광, 노동 분야에서 크게 성장하기도 했습니다. 지금까지 한국은 베트남의 가장 중요한 경제 파트너들 중의 하나가 되었습니다. 베트남도 점점 한국의 중요한 파트너가 되고 있습니다. 현재, 한국은 5,500개의 프로젝트를 가지고 있는 베트남의 주요 외국인 투자자로 약 70만 명의 노동자를 위한 일자리를 창출하고 있습니다. 양국은 2020년까지 1,000억 달러에 이르는 교역액을 달성하기 위해 노력하고 있다.

관광은 양국이 좋은 성과를 거두는 분야이기도 합니다. 2016년에 양국간 관광객 교류는 180만 명에 달했습니다. 한국에서 생활하면서 공부하고 일하고 있는 거의 15만명의 베트남 사람들이 양국의 우호관계와 협력관계를 강화하는 데에 기여하는 중요한 가교 역할을 해 왔습니다. 양국의 국민 교류가 활발해졌습니다.  더욱 더 많은 베트남 사람들, 특히 젊은 세대들이 한국 문화에 대해 알아보고 언어를 배우기 위해 한국으로 가고 반면에, 베트남은 동남아에서 한국인들이 선택한 목적지가 되었습니다.

또한 양국간의 인적과 문화적 교류는 규모나 형식적으로 모두 발전하고 있으며, 이를 통해 양국간 우호관계 및 깊은 이해관계를 더욱 강화하는데 기여하고 있습니다.
지난 25년간에, 한국과 베트남의 협력 관계가 더 돈독해지고, 많은 성과를 거두었음을 알 수 있습니다. 외교관계 수립 25주년 기념은 지난 길을 돌아보며, 협력 우호관계를 한 한층으로 더 발전하고 양국 국민에게 실제적인 이익을 가져오기 위해 효과적인 대책을 지속 제안할 기회입니다.

Comment: you will probably have better luck if you break this down into smaller sections, or have a specific question

Answer (score 1):

I can't make better translations because I don't know what original meaning was so I will just give you some awkward points.

강력한 발전을 달성했으며 - We don't usually use 달성 to 발전

지난 25년간에, 베트남과 한국의(양국의) 관계는 정치, 경제, 협력 개발, 문화, 국민 교류 등 모든 분야에서 빠르고 견고하고 전면적으로 발전해 나가고 있습니다. - You are starting the sentence with past 25 years but it ends with -고 있습니다(present progressive) which is a bit awkward

양국 관계의 발전 과정에 중요한 계기는 2001년 “전면적인 협력관계” 로, 2009년 “전략적 협력동반자 관계”로 격상하는 것입니다. - -것입니다 is meaning future in this case but you are talking about historical events.

지금까지 한국은 베트남의 가장 중요한 경제 파트너들 중의 하나가 되었습니다. 베트남도 점점 한국의 중요한 파트너가 되고 있습니다. - Sentence is not natural.

양국은 2020년까지 1,000억 달러에 이르는 교역액을 달성하기 위해 노력하고 있다. - Sudden use of -이다 instead of -입니다.

관광은 양국이 좋은 성과를 거두는 분야이기도 합니다. - Use of '도' while 관광 was mentioned here first time.

가교 - No problem at all but unfamiliar word

더욱 더 많은 베트남 사람들, 특히 젊은 세대들이 한국 문화에 대해 알아보고 언어를 배우기 위해 한국으로 가고 반면에, 베트남은 동남아에서 한국인들이 선택한 목적지가 되었습니다. - Remove 반면에